# Stop the NYTimes Crossword notifications

Tags: windows-10, notifications

I have recently purchased a new Surface 3 and upgraded it to Win10.  Immediately, I started receiving notifications that the daily NY Times crossword puzzle is available.  Since I'm not one for crossword puzzles, I uninstalled the app.  It's a few days later, and I'm still getting notifications.

I've searched my registry and removed any reference to "NYTimes", "NewYorkTimes", "crossword", and any variation I can conjure with and without spaces.

I've searched the hard drive using [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) and deleted anything related to the app.  (There were a few items I couldn't delete due to access restrictions.  I couldn't explain that either: I'm an admin on this machine.  Why can't I delete a file?)

It doesn't show up in my notifications management list or in Programs and Features.

I've restarted several times.

Any ideas on how I can remove this notification?

Comment: Check in the notification itself whether they have an 'unsubscribe' - usually at the bottom of the notification.

Comment: @whs, for Win10 on the Surface, you have to touch and hold (probably right-click) on the notification, then you get a "stop receiving notifications from this app" option.  Still concerns me that it's running somewhere...  Regardless, write up an answer, and it's yours!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this is an old question, but my Surface recently started doing this and in digging around for a solution I came across this question and a solution to get rid of it instead of just hiding it.

The New York Times Crossword app doesn't show up in Programs and Features because it is a Metro app. You can list and remove them with Powershell.

Open a Powershell window, as Administrator if your regular user is not in the Administrators group and list installed App Packages with

```
    Get-AppxPackage
```

You can filter just the New York Times app with

```
    Get-AppxPackage *york*
```

It's probably the only one with the word york in it so to remove it

```
    GetAppxPackage *york* | Remove-AppxPackage
```

And now it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. type notification into the search bar and go to notification and action settings. uncheck times crossword.